# Объясните поведение "struct line" в коде sort из coreutils

Tags: c, указатели, структуры

Изучаю код coreutils в частности sort. Не могу понять как указатель на структуру line при операциях "line--" и "line + число" перемещается куда нужно...
Например в функции fillbuf строки 1780,1781:

```
struct line *linelim = buffer_linelim (buf);
struct line *line = linelim - buf->nlines;
```

объявляется указатель `linelim` на `struct line`,
указатель указывает на конец выделенной памяти `buf.buf`,
во-второй строке из этого указателя вычитается целое число (количество строк в буфере). Куда теперь указывает этот указатель мне не понятно!...
Далее на строке 1820 `line--`... куда теперь указывает??? на предыдущую строку? а как...???
Мне не нужна помощь в моей программе (пока), я лишь прошу разъяснить "вопрос"

```
/* Lines are held in core as counted strings. */
struct line
{
  char *text;           /* Text of the line. */
  size_t length;        /* Length including final newline. */
  char *keybeg;         /* Start of first key. */
  char *keylim;         /* Limit of first key. */
};
/* Input buffers. */
struct buffer
{
  char *buf;            /* Dynamically allocated buffer,
                                   partitioned into 3 regions:
                                   - input data;
                                   - unused area;
                                   - an array of lines, in reverse order.  */
  size_t used;          /* Number of bytes used for input data.  */
  size_t nlines;        /* Number of lines in the line array.  */
  size_t alloc;         /* Number of bytes allocated. */
  size_t left;          /* Number of bytes left from previous reads. */
  size_t line_bytes;        /* Number of bytes to reserve for each line. */
  bool eof;         /* An EOF has been read.  */
};

static bool
fillbuf (struct buffer *buf, FILE *fp, char const *file)
{
  struct keyfield const *key = keylist;
  char eol = eolchar;
  size_t line_bytes = buf->line_bytes;
  size_t mergesize = merge_buffer_size - MIN_MERGE_BUFFER_SIZE;

  if (buf->eof)
    return false;

  if (buf->used != buf->left)
    {
      memmove (buf->buf, buf->buf + buf->used - buf->left, buf->left);
      buf->used = buf->left;
      buf->nlines = 0;
    }

  while (true)
    {
      char *ptr = buf->buf + buf->used;
      struct line *linelim = buffer_linelim (buf);
      struct line *line = linelim - buf->nlines;
      size_t avail = (char *) linelim - buf->nlines * line_bytes - ptr;
      char *line_start = buf->nlines ? line->text + line->length : buf->buf;

      while (line_bytes + 1 < avail)
        {
          /* Read as many bytes as possible, but do not read so many
             bytes that there might not be enough room for the
             corresponding line array.  The worst case is when the
             rest of the input file consists entirely of newlines,
             except that the last byte is not a newline.  */
          size_t readsize = (avail - 1) / (line_bytes + 1);
          size_t bytes_read = fread (ptr, 1, readsize, fp);
          char *ptrlim = ptr + bytes_read;
          char *p;
          avail -= bytes_read;

          if (bytes_read != readsize)
            {
              if (ferror (fp))
                sort_die (_("read failed"), file);
              if (feof (fp))
                {
                  buf->eof = true;
                  if (buf->buf == ptrlim)
                    return false;
                  if (line_start != ptrlim && ptrlim[-1] != eol)
                    *ptrlim++ = eol;
                }
            }

          /* Find and record each line in the just-read input.  */
          while ((p = memchr (ptr, eol, ptrlim - ptr)))
            {
              /* Delimit the line with NUL. This eliminates the need to
                 temporarily replace the last byte with NUL when calling
                 xmemcoll, which increases performance.  */
              *p = '\0';
              ptr = p + 1;
              line--;
              line->text = line_start;
              line->length = ptr - line_start;
              mergesize = MAX (mergesize, line->length);
              avail -= line_bytes;

              if (key)
                {
                  /* Precompute the position of the first key for
                     efficiency.  */
                  line->keylim = (key->eword == SIZE_MAX
                                  ? p
                                  : limfield (line, key));

                  if (key->sword != SIZE_MAX)
                    line->keybeg = begfield (line, key);
                  else
                    {
                      if (key->skipsblanks)
                        while (blanks[to_uchar (*line_start)])
                          line_start++;
                      line->keybeg = line_start;
                    }
                }

              line_start = ptr;
            }

          ptr = ptrlim;
          if (buf->eof)
            break;
        }

      buf->used = ptr - buf->buf;
      buf->nlines = buffer_linelim (buf) - line;
      if (buf->nlines != 0)
        {
          buf->left = ptr - line_start;
          merge_buffer_size = mergesize + MIN_MERGE_BUFFER_SIZE;
          return true;
        }

      {
        /* The current input line is too long to fit in the buffer.
           Increase the buffer size and try again, keeping it properly
           aligned.  */
        size_t line_alloc = buf->alloc / sizeof (struct line);
        buf->buf = x2nrealloc (buf->buf, &line_alloc, sizeof (struct line));
        buf->alloc = line_alloc * sizeof (struct line);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: почитайте https://metanit.com/cpp/c/5.3.php

Comment: дык от сюда и вопрос! структура лайн и буфер ни как не связаны... размер структуры line совсем не совпадает с длинной строки, а адресная арифметика подразумевает изменение указателя на размер структуры...

Comment: Прогу не вижу, но скорее всего `nlines` - переводиться как количество занятых структур в буфере. и вычитание даёт указатель на начальную структуру в буфере. Лучше попишите сами и свою прогу с вопросом сюда *если что*.

Comment: А почитать арифметику указателей *по ссылке* успели?

Comment: Ну я и пишу свою... хотел взять за основу алгоритм сортировки слиянием... все понятно :-) но не получается. nLines это количество строк прочитанных из файла. В буф читается файл кусками, потом ищется конец строк (заменяется на \0), плюсуется nLine... При выходе из функции Line забывается... т.е. она нужна при поисках конца строк и т.д.... Но потом в вызывающей функции sort опять объявляется указатель line указывающей на конец готового буфера и передается в функцию инициализации нодов (для слияния) и вот там чудеса...

Comment: Скомпилировать мне не удается coreutils... а в моей проге мне надо делать тоже самое только с double не с char... я уже переделал на чар... все равно line куда-то в небо смотрит...

Comment: "А почитать арифметику указателей по ссылке успели?" читал много раз и сейчас еще раз прочитал... ничего нового :-)

Comment: Если всё знаете, тогда можно ответить только с вашей программой.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понимаю, что именно здесь вызывает вопросы, но c `lines`
происходят следующие манипуляции.

---

Как написано в комментариях, буфер состоит из трёх частей:

- входные данные
- пустое место
- массив `struct line` со строками в обратном порядке

т.е. у него будет следующая структура:

```
  +----------------+-----------------+----------------+
  | входные данные | свободное место | lines [nlines] |
  +----------------+-----------------+----------------+
  ^
  |
 buffer.buf
```

`buffer_linelim()` возвращает указатель на конец буфера:

```
  +----------------+-----------------+----------------+
  | входные данные | свободное место | lines [nlines] |
  +----------------+-----------------+----------------+
                                                      ^
                                                      |
                               linelim = buffer_linelim(buf)
```

А `line = linelim - buf->nlines;` вычисляет начало массивы

```
  +----------------+-----------------+----------------+
  | входные данные | свободное место | lines [nlines] |
  +----------------+-----------------+----------------+
                                     ^
                                     |
                               line = linelim - buf->nlines
```

Сам массив `lines` выглядит следующим образом:

```
  -----+-------------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  ...  S     пустое        | стр. S ... S стр.| стр.| стр.|   
  ...  S     место         |  N   S ... S  2  |  1  |  0  |
  -----+-------------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                           ^
                           |
                          line
```

При добавлении новой строки указатель просто перемещается назад
и информация об очередной строке записывается в область пустого
пространства:

```
  -----+-------------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  ...  S     пустое  | стр.| стр. S ... S стр.| стр.| стр.|   
  ...  S     место   | N+1 |  N   S ... S  2  |  1  |  0  |
  -----+-------------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                     ^
                     |
                    line --
```

Comment: т.е я правильно понимаю, что в итоге в буфере хранятся сначала строки (подряд, слитно через \0), потом "struct line" для каждой строки (указатель на начало строки и ее размер...)? Если так, то не понятно как же выделялся буфер... там расчет идет от размера файла... Сейчас обмозгую...

Comment: да всё так... а про буфер — ну как-то он угадывается вначале или задаётся из командной строки... если его не хватает под строку — он расширяется... в общем для алгоритма это не особо интересно...